# How do I set queue settings configuration variables in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, function

I want to set these configuration values for an Azure Function.

```
"extensions": {
  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
    "batchSize": 32,
    "maxDequeueCount": 5,
    "newBatchThreshold": 16
  }
},
```

Do I add them in as their key or would it be like this:

- Key: queues:maxPollingInterval, Value: 00:00:02
- Key: queues:visibilityTimeout, Value: 00:00:30
- Key: queues:batchSize, Value: 32
- Key: queues:maxDequeueCount, Value: 5
- Key: queues:newBatchThreshold, Value: 16

Answer (score 1):

You have to set these values in `host.json` of the Azure function:

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) for **Sample host.json for Azure Functions version 1.x**

```json
{
    "aggregator": {
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
        "sampling": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 5
        }
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00",
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
}
```

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) for **Sample host.json for Azure Functions version 2.x:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "blobs": {},
        "cosmosDb": {},
        "durableTask": {},
        "eventHubs": {},
        "http": {},
        "queues": {},
        "sendGrid": {},
        "serviceBus": {}
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00",
    "logging": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
        "logLevel": {
          "Function.MyFunction": "Information",
          "default": "None"
        },
    },
    "managedDependency": {
        "enabled": true
    }
```

**Example:**

I have created a Queue Triggered Azure function:

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public void Run([QueueTrigger("<queue_name>", Connection = "<Storage_connection_string_name>")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "demo": "<Storage_connection_string>"
  }
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 2,
      "newBatchThreshold": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I set `maxDequeueCount: 2` and raised exception to verify if its working, I could see the message has reached the defined `MaxDequeueCount` i.e., 2.

Response:
[image]

- When the message execution count reaches the  `MaxDequeueCount`, the message will be sent to  `Queue poison`.
- 

[image]

Comment: This is great info. Do you happen to know how I could include these settings in my Configuration values in the azure portal?

Comment: You can add in `Function App=>App Files=>host.json`.

Comment: I've been using the values in Settings=>Configuration as my function app is currently in read only mode because i am running from a package file.

Comment: Is it linux function app?

Comment: You can modify in KUDU site also.

Comment: It's a windows function app

Comment: Navigate to KUDU site of your app(https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net) =>site=>wwwroot, and share the screen shot of the files available.